# Error Creating IPA File for Enterprise Distribution: "PackageApplication failed with exit code 1"

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, code-signing, enterprise

I am running XCode 4.2 and when I Build, Archive, and then attempt to create the IPA file in Organizer, I get the following error message:

```
PackageApplication failed with exit code 1.
Packaging application: '/Users/Brad/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-06/*** 8-6-11 4.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/***.app'
Arguments: embed=/Users/Brad/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/***.mobileprovision  verbose=1  output=/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/1376A091-5CA1-4393-AF29-34FFBFD49C74-1082-00000C64DB251DF1/app.ipa  sign=iPhone Distribution: ***.  
Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/Brad
LOGNAME = Brad
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0:0
DISPLAY = /tmp/launch-r5c1Ou/org.x:0
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
PATH = /Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SHELL = /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-SjRZET/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /tmp/launch-4KUyaU/Render
TMPDIR = /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/
USER = Brad
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.10.0

Output directory: '/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/1376A091-5CA1-4393-AF29-34FFBFD49C74-1082-00000C64DB251DF1/app.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp /Users/Brad/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-06/*** 8-6-11 4.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/***.app /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/Brad/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-06/*** 8-6-11 4.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/***.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/Users/Brad/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-06/*** 8-6-11 4.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/***.app: valid on disk
/Users/Brad/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-06/*** 8-6-11 4.21 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/***.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
]
Done checking the original app
### Embedding '/Users/Brad/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/***.mobileprovision'
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
+ /bin/cp -rp /Users/Brad/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/***.mobileprovision /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app/embedded.mobileprovision
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/codesign -d --entitlements /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/entitlements_rawunFQiwaj /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [Executable=/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app/***
]
+ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Set :get-task-allow NO /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/entitlements_plistNowUyBmz
Program /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy returned 0 : []
+ /usr/bin/plutil -lint /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/entitlements_plistNowUyBmz
Program /usr/bin/plutil returned 0 : [/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/entitlements_plistNowUyBmz: OK
]
### Codesigning '/Users/Brad/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/***.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Distribution: ***.'
+ /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Distribution: ***. --resource-rules=/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/entitlements_plistNowUyBmz /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app: replacing existing signature
codesign_allocate: object: /var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app/*** malformed object (unknown load command 8)
/var/folders/-K/-K95TJ0AGgaHq4MSn8EjL++++TI/-Tmp-/kNwZk2Uc3U/Payload/***.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
]
error: codesign failed with error 1
```

Note: I replaced any names with ***.

Comment: I've got this exact same issue - codesign failed with error 1 - anyone shed any light on this please?

Answer (score 3):

There is no single answer to this problem, partly because Apple's error message(s) is/are not terribly specific.

For my case the solution was this:

Open this Perl script:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication
```

and insert this line near the top, like right after the "my $xxxx" declarations:

```
$ENV{CODESIGN_ALLOCATE} = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate';
```

Credit to http://loopingrecursion.com/index.php?t=codesign for this answer.

The problem seemed to arise after installing some XCode 4.2 beta 7. I eventually uninstalled that one and reinstalled 4.1 from scratch but still couldn't Validate or Share, until I employed this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself a few minutes ago.

Make sure you have a Distribution Certificate in your keychain (you can create one in your Provisioning Portal), and also a Distribution Profile (also you can create this in you Provisioning Portal).

After that, go into your Project properties, to the 'Build Settings' tab.
You'll find a section called 'Code Signing', and at the 'Code Signing Identity' part, at 'Release' you select 'iPhone Distribution'.

That was how i fixed it,

Good luck!

EDIT: just saw you're in the Enterprise program, i'm not sure if my solution works for Enterprise..

Comment: If you're having trouble with your distribution certificate you can revoke it form the provisioning portal and delete it from Keychain Access, then Xcode can automatically generate a correct one in the organizer under devices and then provisioning profiles. Check automatic device provisioning and click refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The "PackageApplication failed with exit code 1." error during archiving can also be caused by a missing resource.  Check your error message for which resource it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my 5 cents on this.  I had the same error and it turned out that I had 2 Distribution certificates in my keychain.  One of them appeared with a red X next to it.  After deleting it the error was resolved.